# TypeError: cafile, capath and cadata cannot be all omitted in only the exe format

Tags: python, websocket

I am getting error on connecting socket, when I run python code it work fine despite the exe format,
I tried some solutions on internet but nothing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "threading.py", line 870, in run
  File "spectre_code.py", line 242, in start
  File "websocket\_core.py", line 211, in connect
  File "websocket\_http.py", line 77, in connect
  File "websocket\_http.py", line 179, in _ssl_socket
  File "websocket\_http.py", line 138, in _wrap_sni_socket
TypeError: cafile, capath and cadata cannot be all omitted
```

I tried this:

```
ssl_defaults = ssl.get_default_verify_paths()
sslopt_ca_certs = {'ca_certs': ssl_defaults.cafile}
history = websocket.WebSocket(sslopt=sslopt_ca_certs)
history.connect("wss://wss.hyper-api.com:5553/spectreai/",
                                            header=[protocol_str])
```

But still not working, is the problem in library downloading, thanks!

Comment: Where did you find `'ca_certs'` as the key?  The Python `ssl` module wants, as it says, either `cafile`, `capath`, or `cadata` to specify the live certificate.

Comment: Actually I don't know if I should import the cert to the file, but the thing why it doesn't work in exe?

Comment: Did you add the certificate as a data file when you built the exe?  You need to tell the pyinstaller about any extra files you need.

Comment: The file there should be already in the library of websocket

Comment: Have you verified that the `ca_certs` value is not empty?